# Entity framework with OData(Web API) is sending Order By clause By default to Sql Query

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am using Web Api with OData. and I have an entity defined in an EF 5.0.
I am sending very simple request to Controller::

```
 $.ajax({url: "/odata/Details?$top=10",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
               viewModel.list(data.value);
            }
```

Now code on My controller::

```
 [Queryable]
    public override IQueryable<Area> Get()
    {  
    return db.Area.AsQueryable();
    }
```

Query i see using SQL Profiler::

```
 SELECT TOP (@p__linq__1) 
[Project1].[id] AS [id1], 
[Project1].[name] AS [name1], 
[Project1].[pucrhase] AS [pucrhase1], 
[Project1].[sale] AS [sale1]
FROM Area
ORDER BY [Project1].[id] DESC, [Project1].[name] ASC, [Project1].[pucrhase] ASC,      
[Project1].[sale] ASC,N',@p__linq__1 int,@p__linq__1=10
```

I have not requested for any Ordering , Order By Clause . EF adds ORDER BY clause by Itself to Query. Order By clause added contains all columns of table.This table has 3 millions records and Query is timing Out as it is Ordering by All columns .

I tested by removing Order By it took Less then a second to finish

So Question is

how to Stop Entity framework(support of Web Api Odata ) from sending Order By clause to Sql Query.

How to remove Order By clause from SQL Query Entity framework(Web Api Odata) runs on Server?

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039550/how-can-i-keep-entity-framework-from-generating-inefficient-queries-in-sql-serve

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Im not sure if this is the right answer,  but im assuming that the odata service is attempting to maintain a stable sort ordering by ordering on all properties within your model.

Therefore try

```
[Queryable(EnsureStableOrdering=false)]
```

Comment: Thanks and i appreciate your help. i have one more Question :) its working for me for url's like this url:     "/odata/Details?$top=10"

Comment: If i add Skip parameter to do client side paging and [Queryable(EnsureStableOrdering=false]                                  url: "/odata/Details?$top=10$skip=10" .No query runs on Server .I did not see any Query run on Sql profiler . It looks like Entity framework is not sending any Query to Sql Server.

Comment: Can you please tell me why SKIP odata parameter does not work with [Queryable(EnsureStableOrdering=false] ?

Comment: Im going to assume this is actually because $top and $skip don't make sense if you can't guarantee the order.   why don't you just order by id or some other column by default.

Comment: Woww Great :) Thanks alot .You saved my lot of time.

Comment: I used Url like this Ajax request::                                 url: "/odata/details?$top=10&$skip=10&$orderby=id asc"                      Its Working fine

Comment: +1 Thanks I had the same problem with my WebApi backed by NHibernate - all the properties on the Entity that are NOT mapped to the database were causing NH to choke.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OData controller + CosmosDb data, entity framework sends `order by c.Id` by default.

If you add manually another `orderby=field1 asc` for instance it will add another clause to query which will cause an error from cosmos

Add this to your data controller, it will remove the default Id ordering

`[EnableQuery(EnsureStableOrdering = false)]`