# How to get EntityFramework to efficiently execute an OrderBy when using Linq and ODataQueryOptions?

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, odata

The following method WebAPI method accepts an OData request and I would like to order by `GeoDisplay`:

```
    public virtual IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<GeoLocation> odataQueryOptions)
    {
        . . . 
            var results = odataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(_repository
                .ODataQueryable()
                .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
                .OrderBy(o => o.GeoDisplay)).Cast<GeoLocation>()
                .Select(s => new GeoLocationDTO()
                {
                    // projection
                    GeoId = s.GeoId,
                    GeoCity = s.GeoCity,
                    GeoState = s.GeoState,
                    GeoDisplay = s.GeoDisplay,
                    GeoUrl = s.GeoUrl,
                    GeoDescription = s.GeoDescription
                });

            var r = results.ToList();
```

The problem is that the output is not ordered.  When I look at the query execution in SQL Server Profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (@p__linq__1) 
    [Project1].[GeoID] AS [GeoID], 
    [Project1].[GeoCity] AS [GeoCity], 
    [Project1].[GeoState] AS [GeoState], 
    [Project1].[GeoDisplay] AS [GeoDisplay], 
    [Project1].[GeoUrl] AS [GeoUrl], 
    [Project1].[GeoDescription] AS [GeoDescription]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[GeoID] AS [GeoID], 
        [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Extent1].[GeoDisplay] AS [GeoDisplay], 
        [Extent1].[GeoUrl] AS [GeoUrl], 
        [Extent1].[GeoCity] AS [GeoCity], 
        [Extent1].[GeoState] AS [GeoState], 
        [Extent1].[GeoDescription] AS [GeoDescription], 
        [Extent1].[WorldCitiesID] AS [WorldCitiesID], 
        [Extent1].[GAAccountCode] AS [GAAccountCode], 
        [Extent1].[EnableTopSearches] AS [EnableTopSearches], 
        [Extent1].[EnableCalculatedTopGeoSearches] AS [EnableCalculatedTopGeoSearches], 
        [Extent1].[msrepl_tran_version] AS [msrepl_tran_version]
        FROM [dbo].[GeoLocations] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[EnableCalculatedTopGeoSearches] ASC, [Project1].[EnableTopSearches] ASC, [Project1].[GAAccountCode] ASC, [Project1].[GeoCity] ASC, [Project1].[GeoDescription] ASC, [Project1].[GeoDisplay] ASC, [Project1].[GeoID] ASC, [Project1].[GeoState] ASC, [Project1].[GeoUrl] ASC, [Project1].[msrepl_tran_version] ASC, [Project1].[UserId] ASC, [Project1].[WorldCitiesID] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 int',@p__linq__0=102,@p__linq__1=30
```

It appears that EF has added it's own `OrderBy` rules - by fields that I'm not even interested in.

So I figure, I'll just move the `OrderBy` portion a little further down the Linq chain:

```
            var results = odataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(_repository
                .ODataQueryable()
                .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)).Cast<GeoLocation>()
                .OrderBy(o => o.GeoDisplay)
                .Select(s => new GeoLocationDTO()
                { . . .
```

This does render the desired result, however the executed query is pretty nasty looking:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Project2].[GeoID] AS [GeoID], 
    [Project2].[GeoCity] AS [GeoCity], 
    [Project2].[GeoState] AS [GeoState], 
    [Project2].[GeoDisplay] AS [GeoDisplay], 
    [Project2].[GeoUrl] AS [GeoUrl], 
    [Project2].[GeoDescription] AS [GeoDescription]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (@p__linq__1) 
        [Project1].[GeoID] AS [GeoID], 
        [Project1].[GeoDisplay] AS [GeoDisplay], 
        [Project1].[GeoUrl] AS [GeoUrl], 
        [Project1].[GeoCity] AS [GeoCity], 
        [Project1].[GeoState] AS [GeoState], 
        [Project1].[GeoDescription] AS [GeoDescription]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[GeoID] AS [GeoID], 
            [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
            [Extent1].[GeoDisplay] AS [GeoDisplay], 
            [Extent1].[GeoUrl] AS [GeoUrl], 
            [Extent1].[GeoCity] AS [GeoCity], 
            [Extent1].[GeoState] AS [GeoState], 
            [Extent1].[GeoDescription] AS [GeoDescription], 
            [Extent1].[WorldCitiesID] AS [WorldCitiesID], 
            [Extent1].[GAAccountCode] AS [GAAccountCode], 
            [Extent1].[EnableTopSearches] AS [EnableTopSearches], 
            [Extent1].[EnableCalculatedTopGeoSearches] AS [EnableCalculatedTopGeoSearches], 
            [Extent1].[msrepl_tran_version] AS [msrepl_tran_version]
            FROM [dbo].[GeoLocations] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL)
        )  AS [Project1]
        ORDER BY [Project1].[EnableCalculatedTopGeoSearches] ASC, [Project1].[EnableTopSearches] ASC, [Project1].[GAAccountCode] ASC, [Project1].[GeoCity] ASC, [Project1].[GeoDescription] ASC, [Project1].[GeoDisplay] ASC, [Project1].[GeoID] ASC, [Project1].[GeoState] ASC, [Project1].[GeoUrl] ASC, [Project1].[msrepl_tran_version] ASC, [Project1].[UserId] ASC, [Project1].[WorldCitiesID] ASC
    )  AS [Project2]
    ORDER BY [Project2].[GeoDisplay] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 int',@p__linq__0=102,@p__linq__1=30
```

As you can see, the initial EF-versioned `OrderBy` is still in there (`ORDER BY [Project1]...`), then my desired `OrderBy` is applied.

How can I eliminate that first `OrderBy` from the mix?

Comment: Check out this answer to a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16052586/219072

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking at the actual request, I realized that the incoming default OData query options were being applied.  All I had to do was ensure that I was applying the appropriate filtering and sorting parameters before the request got to the controller.

In my case, I am using a KendoUI data source and applied the following to the ds:

```
    serverSorting: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverPaging: true,
    filter: {},
    sort: { field: "GeoDisplay", dir: "asc" },
```

Even though no filter is being applied, if you want to enable server-side filtering, initialize the ds with an empty filter (or sort).

The resulting request is as follows:

```
/odata/AccountGeoLocations?$format=json&$inlinecount=allpages&$orderby=GeoDisplay&$top=30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the query options you want one by one.

```
var results = _repository
                    .ODataQueryable()
                    .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
                    .OrderBy(o => o.GeoDisplay)).Cast<GeoLocation>()
                    .Select(s => new GeoLocationDTO()
                    {
                        // projection
                        GeoId = s.GeoId,
                        GeoCity = s.GeoCity,
                        GeoState = s.GeoState,
                        GeoDisplay = s.GeoDisplay,
                        GeoUrl = s.GeoUrl,
                        GeoDescription = s.GeoDescription
                    };
    results = odataQueryOptions.Filter == null ? 
                  results : 
                  odataQueryOptions.Filter.ApplyTo(results, new ODataQuerySettings());
    ......
    /*Apply any query option you want, Filter, OrderBy, Skip, Top, InlineCount...*/
```

### ......

***Update:***

Sorry I misunderstood your question.

I think the auto-generated orderby is the default behavior of entity framework.

Check this for a solution.

[How can I keep Entity Framework from generating inefficient queries in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039550/how-can-i-keep-entity-framework-from-generating-inefficient-queries-in-sql-serve)

Comment: You still have the `OrderBy` in the first part of the Linq statement, and when I try this, I get the following exception: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<GeoLocationDTO>'`